# Instal rbenv on gnome to allow installation of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I have a virtual machine and run Ubuntu 32 bit on it (unsure of release as don't know where to find properties of release).  The terminal is Gnome 3.18.3.

I wish to install rbenv, which I believe will then allow me to install rails.

Please can somebody list line by line instructions and code that I can follow to overcome this obstacle for both the installation of the rbenv and rails.

Thank you in advance

Brendan

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to install dependencies,**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev
```

**Download and Install rbenv:**

To install rbenv run this in terminal:

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
```

Add rbenv to your `.bashrc

`vim ~/.bashrc` and add

```
export RBENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.rbenv"
# export RBENV_ROOT="/opt/rbenv/" 
# some developers prefare this option I highly recommend to install rbenv to home folder of deploy user as it's convention 

if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

next you need to load bashrc changes

```
. ~/.bashrc 
bash
```

**Install Ruby of your choice:**

```
rbenv install 2.3.1
```

...this will take some time.

Set your newly installed ruby as global (default)

```
rbenv global 2.3.1
```

To check what is the current global ruby version

```
rbenv version
# => 2.3.1
```

to list all rbenv versions:

```
rbenv versions
```

**Install Rails:**

Installing Rails is as simple as running the following command in your Terminal:

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.6
```

Rails is now installed, but in order for us to use the rails executable, we need to tell rbenv to see it:

```
rbenv rehash
```

And now we can verify Rails is installed:

```
rails -v
# Rails 4.2.6
```